# Copying all the files modified this month from the command line

Tags: shell, grep, pipe, ls

I want to copy all the files in a directory that were modified this month. I can list those files like this:

```
ls -l * | grep Jul
```

And then to copy them I was trying to pipe the result into `cp` via `xargs` but had no success (I think) because I couldn't figure out how to parse the `ls -l` output to just grab the filename for `cp`.

I'm sure there are many ways of doing this; I'll give the correct answer out to the person who can show me how to parse `ls -l` in this manner (or talk me down from that position) though I'd be interested in seeing other methods as well.

Thanks!

Comment: [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, just doing `grep Jul` is bad because you might have files with `Jul` in their name.

Actually, `find` is probably the right tool for your job. Something like this:

```
find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -30 -exec cp {} $DEST/ \;
```

where `$DIR` is the directory where your files are (e.g. '.') and `$DEST` is the target directory.

- The `-maxdepth 1` flag means it doesn't look inside sub-directories for files (isn't recursive)
- The `-type f` flag means it looks only at regular files (e.g. not directories)
- The `-mtime -30` means it looks at files with modification time newer than 30 days (+30 would be older than 30 days)
- the `-exec` flag means it executes the following command on each file, where `{}` is replaced with the file name and `\;` is the end of the command

Answer (score 1):

interested in seeing how this might be done with zsh

```
ls -lt *.*(mM0)
```

last month

```
ls -lt *.*(mM1)
```

or for precise date date ranges

```
autoload -U age
ls -tl *.*(e#age 2014/06/07 now#)
ls -tl *.*(e#age 2014/06/01 2014/06/20#)
```